# Find out who didn't pay in a monthly billing system

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2014

I'm creating system for manage shops rent. I have 4 tables (customers, shops, contracts, payments).

And this is the 4 tables:

customers :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customers](
    [cust_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [nickname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [phone1] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [phone2] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [phone3] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [image] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [image_exist] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
```

shops :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[shops](
    [shop_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [size] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [floor] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
```

Contracts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[contracts](
    [con_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cust_id] [int] NULL,
    [shop_id] [int] NULL,
    [con_duration] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [price] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [con_use] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [rent_type] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [price2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [note2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [image] [image] NULL,
    [date_start] [date] NULL,
    [date_end] [date] NULL,
    [note] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [image_exist] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
```

Payments:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payments_monthly](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [con_id] [int] NULL,
    [pay_number] [nvarchar](50) NULL, \\ i get the duration from contact and make numbers of payments, if the duration was 12 then the pay_number will be 1,2,3,.....,12- so the customers need to pay 12 time , one time per month
    [pay_value] [decimal](18, 0) NULL, \\ amount of payment  
    [pay_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ch_number] [int] NULL,
    [note] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
```

So what I need is get all customers that didn't pay for this month or specific month the user chose (note : not all customers must pay in the same date, maybe some need to pay on 10-9-2017 or some 20-9-2017) so I need all customers who must pay in the September (1-9-2017 to 30-92017).

So what I need to change in my tables to achieve my goals, or query.

I am working on a program to manage a group of shops and these shops rented for a certain period, so the contract is 6 months, 12 months, 18 or 24 ... etc.
there is 2 type of contracts:

1-(The contract is a certain period and the payment is one time)

2-(the contract is a certain period and the payment per month in a certain amount per month)

For example:

- 1: 12000 $ for 12 months - paid once (stored in payment_yearly table)
- Contract 2: 12000 $ for 12 months - paid more than once - the payment will be as follows (12000/12 = 1000 $per month) (stored in the payment_monthly table)

The program worked as follows:

Table of tenants

And a table for rented shops

A table of contracts (in which the customers and the shops premises are connected)

After that,  2 tables for monthly payments and yearly payments. Payments are recorded for each contract (linked to the customer and the shop)

[image: Diagram]

Comment: The logic seems rather simple. Select the customer details you want where an entry exists in the contracts table with date_start before the first of the month and date_end after the first of the month and an entry in the payments table for that month doesn't exist. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: @ZLK Thank you for replay, can you help me with the select statement please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if they're late and pay two months at the same time, so on Sept 1 you get payments for August and September? A traditional accounting system would also have an Invoices table where each month a new invoice is created, and when a payment is made it's applied to the appropriate invoice. Then it's a simple matter of looking for open invoices.

Here's how I would create a simple invoice table:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , con_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Invoices(con_id)
    , invoice_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
    , payment_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.payments(id)
    )
```

It references both the contract and the payment record. On the first of each month, run a process that automatically generates a new invoice for each active contract. Then, when a payment comes in, add the payment ID to the invoice so you know it's paid.

This is a fairly simple system, though, because it assumes only one payment can be applied to one invoice, which only makes sense if nobody ever makes a partial payment. A better option would be to create another table with a many-to-many relationship between payments and invoices:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_payments (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , invoice_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.invoices(ID)
    , payment_id INT REFERENCES dbo.payments(id)
    , DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
    )
```

Now you can apply any number of payments to any number of invoices, and you can create a query that adds up all invoices and all payments to ensure that the client has paid all of their obligations!

Comment: Yes, agree with this. Merely looking at the last payment date does not say if their total payments are up to date. One could do a real-time sum of everything owed to date, but that's rather inefficient.

Comment: @Russell Fox So you suggest to creat new table ( invoice ), when the customer pay the month value , store new details in the new table . Ok i think this better if the user want to print an old pay bill also . But can you explain to me more how this solve what I’m trying to achieve. Thank you

Comment: @Russell Fox, help please :)

Comment: Sorry @Rabeeaqabaha, I just got in front of my computer: I expanded my answer with examples about how to accomplish what you need. You'll still need to create a stored procedure to auto-generate the invoices, so let us know if you need help with that, too. And, of course, you'll need an interface where users can enter this kind of information (unless you just do it yourself on the back end).

Comment: Also, if the contract amount changes, it would be wise to add the price to the invoice.

Comment: @RussellFox thanks for your time, but can you show me how to " On the first of each month, run a process that automatically generates a new invoice for each active contract."

Answer (score 0):

I think the following example might give you some pointers

```
DECLARE @PaymentMonth INT

-- For Semptember 2017 set the variable to
SET @PaymentMonth = 201709

-- For March 2016 set the variable to
-- SET @PaymentMonth = 201603

SELECT c.Name
FROM customers cust
INNER JOIN contracts cont ON cust.cust_id = cont.cust_id
LEFT JOIN payments_monthly p ON cont.con_id = p.con_id
WHERE DATEPART(year, p.date) * 100 + DATEPART(month, p.date) <> @PaymentMonth
```